# how to fix error create key registry read-only

Tags: c#, registrykey

My code here:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegistryKey Hklm = Registry.LocalMachine;
    RegistryKey HkSoftware = Hklm.OpenSubKey("Software");
    RegistryKey HkMicrosoft = HkSoftware.OpenSubKey("Microsoft");
    RegistryKey HkWindows = HkMicrosoft.OpenSubKey("Windows");
    RegistryKey HkMine = HkWindows.CreateSubKey("WindowsUpdate", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
    HkMine.SetValue("NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers", 1);
}
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

In visual studio it given to me it's error:

Comment: Post the error message and line that's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Applications not running with admin rights (elevated) are not allowed to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Microsoft has been warning about this for years. When you debug an application in Visual Studio, the application is started with the same user rights Visual Studio is running under.

The solution is to run the Visual Studio as administrator for debugging.